# preg_match_all grab inside html comment

Tags: php, pcre, preg-match-all

A seen in the title, here the HTML Code example:

```
<body>
<!--CODE_START-->
<p>I <strong>Want</strong> this</p>
<p>And this one too</p>
<!--CODE_STOP-->

<p>This sould be go to trash</p>

<!--CODE_START-->
<p>This one should be included too</p>
<!--CODE_STOP-->
```

The question is, I want everything inside `<!--CODE_START-->` and `<!--CODE_STOP-->` so the result should be:

```
<p>I <strong>Want</strong> this</p>
<p>And this one too</p>
```

and `<p>This one should be included too</p>`

I tried using this `/<!--CODE_START-->([^<]*)<!--CODE_STOP-->/` and `/<!--CODE_START-->(.*)<!--CODE_STOP-->/` with combination of pattern modifiers like `su`, `imu`, `im` it won't work, just return an empty array. And also, its full HTML page that i was try to grab.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[^<]` means everything that is not a <, obviously it's going to fail at **<** p>. Just catch everything and use the non greedy option :

```
preg_match_all('/<!--CODE_START-->(.*)<!--CODE_STOP-->/sU', $foo);
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to put this, I've been try this before, but it just same, have an empty array result.